# Why are my NHibernate queries so slow?

Tags: c#, sql, performance, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm building an ASP web forms app with Fluent NHibernate v2.0.50727 to SQL server backend.

For some reason querying tables with small data (~14 rows) takes seconds.

The maps are all simple: `Id(x => x.Id)` and `Map(x => x.Name)`. CertificateGroup also Map()'s `Color` and `Rank`.

I've isolated the nhibernate code for testing:(this is not representative of my application but is simplified and isolated for SO)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var config = Fluently.Configure()
                             .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString("..."))
                             .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<PersonMap>())                                 .BuildConfiguration();
    var factory = config.BuildSessionFactory();

    using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
    {
        using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var departments = session.QueryOver<DepartmentModel>().List(); // these all take seconds to execute - this has 14 results
            var jobs = session.QueryOver<JobModel>().List(); // 113 results
            var certificates = session.QueryOver<CertificateModel>().List(); //this one about 4 seconds for 210 results
            var groups = session.QueryOver<CertificateGroupModel>().List();

            var association = new CertificateAssociationModel
                {
                    Department = departments.First(),
                    Job = jobs.First(),
                    Certificate = certificates.First(),
                    Group = groups.First()
                };
            session.SaveOrUpdate(association);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

I swapped nhibernate for entity framework and ran the above code and the fetches were instant.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT:

Here are the mappings (as I explained above):
For Department, Job and Certificate:

```
public class DepartmentMap : ClassMap<DepartmentModel>
{
    public DepartmentMap()
    {
        Table("tblDepartment");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

`CertificateGroupModel` also has 
    `Map(x => x.Rank);`
           `Map(x => x.Color);`

Entity classes are all the same:

```
public class CertificateModel
{
    public virtual Int32 Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Except CertificateGroupModel which also has:

```
public virtual String Color { get; set; }
public virtual Int32 Rank { get; set; }
```

Here are my NHiberate profiler results:

```
 -- statement #1
begin transaction with isolation level: Unspecified

-- statement #2
SELECT this_.Id   as Id4_0_,
       this_.Name as Name4_0_
FROM   tblDepartment this_

-- statement #3
SELECT this_.Id   as Id5_0_,
       this_.Type as Type5_0_
FROM   tblJobTitles this_

-- statement #4
SELECT this_.Id   as Id2_0_,
       this_.Name as Name2_0_
FROM   tblCertificate this_

-- statement #5
SELECT this_.Id    as Id1_0_,
       this_.Name  as Name1_0_,
       this_.Rank  as Rank1_0_,
       this_.Color as Color1_0_
FROM   tbl_certificate_groups this_

-- statement #6
INSERT INTO lnk_certificate_associations
            (Certificate_id,
             Department_id,
             Job_id,
             Group_id)
VALUES      (1 /* @p0 */,
             1 /* @p1 */,
             1 /* @p2 */,
             1 /* @p3 */);



select SCOPE_IDENTITY()


-- statement #7
commit transaction
```

[nhibprofile http://i.snag.gy/bTKHm.jpg](http://i.snag.gy/bTKHm.jpg)

IL code generated:

```
                      var departments = session.QueryOver<DepartmentModel>().List();
IL_008F: ldloc.2      /* session */
IL_0090: callvirt     instance NHibernate.IQueryOver`2<!!0, !!0> NHibernate.ISession::QueryOver<Core.Domain.Model.DepartmentModel>()
IL_0095: callvirt     instance [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<!0> NHibernate.IQueryOver`1<Core.Domain.Model.DepartmentModel>::List()
IL_009A: stloc.s      departments
```

Comment: I don't see anything out of the ordinary here, maybe save for creating the `ISessionFactory` on each page load; it should only be done once. Other than that it should run just as good as EF, the generated SQL speaks for itself, there's nothing special there.

Comment: No, I have just isolated the problem code for testing/solving. There is no slowness in creating the factory. The issue is with the querying. Obviously in my application I reuse the session factory.

Comment: The generated SQL is indeed correct. I have to wait seconds for `session.QueryOver<DepartmentModel>().List();` etc to execute. I can't understand why it would take seconds.

Comment: What is the `NhibernateQueryInterceptor`?

Comment: I's an `EmptyInterceptor` and it just overrides OnPrepareStatement and outputs to Debug. I added it to see if the query was correct. It was slow before adding it.

Comment: Are there many DepartmentModels?

Comment: Your transaction process should be handled in a try-catch-finally block  to ensure that the transaction is either committed or rollbacked and does not retain locks on any table.

Comment: @jbl, please read the question.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger No, 14.

Comment: That is one hell of a nasty config statement... have a read of http://entron.wordpress.com/2010/01/06/optimizing-application-startup-time-with-fluent-nhibernate-and-unhaddins/ to optimise fluent config

Comment: @EdwardMulraney I read your question. Even for testing purpose, you should keep the try-catch-finally block. Any orphan lock would just kill your tests. Anyway NH Profiler might be useful in this situation. There is an eval version. It might give you some clues. http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof

Comment: Are you just timing the first query, or multiple queries. There is some overhead in the first connection (~250ms - 500ms) before pooling kicks in and sometimes it can be your database warming up as well

Comment: I did, and you are not explicit that it is the querying that is slow... oh wait, I didn't scroll right to see the timings alongside the query :D

Comment: It may be lazily initializing something ...  I don't know ... e.g. Proxy class generation, JIT-compilation... Take the debug assemblies from NH and pause the debugger during this 10 secs and see where it spends the time. Use SQL profiler to observe when it starts executing queries. Write some log. I don't think that the code we see here is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @StefanSteinegger. There are no objects to lazy load, they're all just {Id, Name} object's at the moment.

Comment: @EdwardMulraney have you tried running the same code twice (copy paste it, so its run twice with the same configured factory and shows two session in NHProf)

Comment: @Edward Mulraney: you should *still* use the debugger to see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, since you haven't posted your mappings and tables here...

Do you have any nullable columns in your database that are mapped to not-nullable types (eg. nullable int mapped to int in your model)?

This can cause the sort of behaviour you're seeing because when NHibernate loads your entities (let's assume the above scenario for DepartmentModel, with a property Prop1 that's an int), if Prop1 is null in the database, then the session will have an internal state for null, but since you cant set Prop1 = null, it will be assigned a value of 0, and when the session checks if anything has changed, it will see that Prop1 has changed (from null to 0), and cause a whole bunch of updates, which will in turn slow things down a lot.

The solution if this is the case would be to either update your table definitions or update your entities to have the correct (nullable) types.

There are various ways this can happen, I've just given a simple example - it would help if you could include your mappings, table definitions and entity classes...

Comment: My database tables match what's mapped except for CertificateModel which has a few more columns which are not mapped for now. Will update to include entity classes but they are exactly as you imagine.

Comment: I didn't think it could be a database issue as there is no issue with Entity Framework (with entity framework equivalent mapping)

Comment: Entity Framework doesn't handle null / dirty issues the same as NHibernate - having said that, the only property that could have this issue would be Rank on CertificateGroupModel, and the slow query is before you query that - maybe try profiling with dotTrace or something similar?

Comment: I've updated the question to include NHibernateProfiler image where the select statements are taking seconds. For some reason DepartmentModel Name was nullable in db, as was CertificateGroup Rank. They are now not nullable and the performance is the same.

Comment: The queries themselves should not take long (otherwise it would be slow using EF), so something in the code is taking time - NHibernate Profiler doesn't really show you what's slowing things down if your queries are fine, hence I'd suggest using a .NET profiling tool to profile your application itself, which should show you what's causing the problem

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If by my code you mean my models, I don't think it can be them. The nhibernate QueryOver is taking long. Are you suggesting I look into NHibernate code to see what's slow in there?

Comment: I mean that this is a bit of a wild goose chase, I would suggest using a .NET profiler (like dotTrace) to see where things are slowing down - whether it's your code or NHibernate I don't know, but a profiler will give you a much better idea

Answer (score 0):

As for the insert questions if you're using Identity generator for Id's then nHibernate will first ask database (`INSERT...SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`) to create record for your entity and then insert it with correct Id and data (`UPDATE`)

Note that references to other entities will be updated in the `UPDATE` therefor you only see '?' in the insert

Comment: Interesting, it doesn't seem to be doing the update after the insert?

Comment: That's because it's not EdwardMulraney, @tchrikch is wrong. NHibernate needs to update the model with the Id after inserting so the Id is selected back, this prevents batch inserts from occuring so it's not recommended you use Identity (which has a bunch of other problems with it too) http://www.philliphaydon.com/2011/09/the-benefits-of-letting-the-orm-generate-the-identity-part-1/

Comment: @EdwardMulraney try to save new entity with a collection and you will see it.

Comment: @tchrikch that only occurs when you get the collection mapping wrong by inversing it.